# In tensorflow, why do the predictions are two dimensional?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, data-science

As I'm learning Tensorflow, I have a confusion about the dimensions of the output layer tensor.

I am learning how to build a multilayer_perceptron model in Tensorflow. The code I'm starting from is [this one](https://github.com/dmesquita/understanding_tensorflow_nn).

In short, it's basically as the below frame:

```
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    :
    :

pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)
    :
    :

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
         :
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    print ("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: X_test, y: y_test_onehot}))
```

I understand the concepts of `argmax` and `equal` methods. But why in `tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))` the axis argument is 1? Or to say, why the `pred` is more than 1 dimension? To me, the `pred` shall be just similar to a 1D array. E.g. [0,1,1,1,1] means except the first prediction, all others are right. And why we need a argmax before the equal method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the MLP model is used for classification, usually, the final layer is a standard linear layer that projects the last hidden layer into the output layer. This last has the same number of units as your number of classes (this output units are often called logits).

Then, this output layer is often provided to a softmax function that push the maximum up and all the others down. In other words, it performs a "soft" max (where with max we mean the array of zeros everywhere and a one in the maximum element).

In the code the multilayer perceptron function returns actually the logits nodes. Logits can be seen as a "degree of confidence" for each of the output classes. Eventually, you'll need the argmax to select the class with the highest degree, the class you are more confident with.

The `pred` tensor returned by the `multilayer_perceptron` function is [batch_size x num_classes]. For each example provided in input, you have num_classes degree of confidence and you need an argmax to extract the index of the right class (maximum degree of confidence).

P.S. Just to keep in mind that this is a multiclass classification problem, where each output node of the network is linked to the prediction about a single class. Each output node `i` has the task of deciding if the input belong to the `i` class or not.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I have edited the post so that the link is shown. You can also click here: https://github.com/dmesquita/understanding_tensorflow_nn. It's indeed a multiclass classification problem. And I guess the problem does lay on the key word "softmax". But why in tensorflow the prediction is shown as softmax matrix (only one 1 in a row)? In the link code, "softmax" only appears in the definition of `loss`.

Comment: Exactly, in the code the multilayer perceptron function returns the logits node. Logits can be seen as a "degree of confidence" for each of the output classes. Eventually, you'll need the argmax to select the class with the highest degree, the class you are more confident with.

Comment: Got it. I checked the logits node info and you are right. Thanks Giuseppe! No idea why my question is marked as -1 now...I did try to ask question in a smooth way

Comment: I'll try to edit it to make it useful to others too. Accept it, if it has solved your doubts

Comment: Done. Really nice and useful suggestions!